# Is there an eval-defun alternative for Clojure mode?

Tags: clojure, cider

When I define a function in Emacs Lisp mode, you can evaluate it with moving the pointer to the
last parenthese of a function, and do <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd>. Aka calling `eval-last-sexp`.

I thought this is somewhat a cumbersome. So I bound the key <kbd>C-e</kbd> to
`eval-defun`. So every time you define a new `setq` definition or a function,
you can evaluate it with `eval-defun` without the need to move your pointer to
the latest parenthese first.

Now I'm trying Clojure in pair with CIDER. I noticed you need to move to the
latest parenthese and then call `cider-eval-last-sexp`. I would like to eval the
current function/whatever where my cursor is, where the pointer is.

But I couldn't find any Clojure/Cider alternative for ELisp's `eval-defun`. Any suggestion for a function would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-M-x` does the right thing in Clojure buffers for me after spawning a REPL.  To look up what command is bound to it, use `F1 k <key sequence>` and you'd find out that it's `cider-eval-defun-at-point`.

Comment: Never discovered the `C-M-x` and thus `cider-eval-defun-at-point`. Thanks for your answer!